# .NET 6 - Model Binding a Dictionary property returning unexpected value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, .net-6.0

On my PageModel, I have a property that is of type `ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>` and I want to bind that property. However, applying the `[BindProperty]` attribute to that property doesn't work. The dictionary is populated with information about the PageModel itself, not the expected content of the dictionary.

### Page:

```
@page
@model MyApp.Pages.MyPageModel

<h6>Dictionary</h6>
<dl>
    @foreach (var key in Model.Dict.Keys)
    {
        <dt>@key</dt>
        <dd>@Model.Dict[key]</dd>
    }
</dl>

<h6>Concurrent Dictionary</h6>
<dl>
    @foreach (var key in Model.ConcurrentDict.Keys)
    {
        <dt>@key</dt>
        <dd>@Model.ConcurrentDict[key]</dd>
    }
</dl>

<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

### PageModel:

```
namespace MyApp.Pages;

using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

[AllowAnonymous]
public class MyPageModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> ConcurrentDict { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Dict { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        ConcurrentDict = new()
        {
            ["concurrent_foo"] = "concurrent_bar"
        };

        Dict = new()
        {
            ["foo"] = "bar"
        };

        return this.Page();
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        return this.Page();
    }
}
```

### After a GET request:

[image: response for GET request]

### After a POST request (form submission):

[image: response for POST request]

Anyone have an idea what's going on here? Any known work-around? Obviously .NET's built-in model binding doesn't play nicely with dictionaries... But I sure would like it to.

Comment: Why do you want to bind to a dictionary, let alone a concurrent one?

Comment: We store localized content in a dictionary. And that dictionary needs to be manipulated asynchronously. Hence using a concurrent dictionary.

Comment: That really doesn't make sense to me in the context of a Razor page, but if you think you need it, it's a valid question of course. But that what you bind a page against, does not have to match the internal data structure you want to manipulate. You also don't _have to_ bind against Entity Framework entities, for example, but you create an `EditFooModel` that you map to and from your entity. Abstractions and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the values of dictionaries when submitting the form.If you don't want to show the inputs,add `hidden`:

```
<form method="post">

    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.ConcurrentDict.Count; i++)
    {
        <input name="ConcurrentDict[@i].Key" value="@Model.ConcurrentDict.ElementAt(i).Key" hidden />
        <input name="ConcurrentDict[@i].Value" value="@Model.ConcurrentDict.ElementAt(i).Value" hidden />
    }
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Dict.Count; i++)
    {
        <input name="Dict[@i].Key" value="@Model.Dict.ElementAt(i).Key" hidden />
        <input name="Dict[@i].Value" value="@Model.Dict.ElementAt(i).Value" hidden />
    }
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: well, I feel sheepish. I was under the impression that if you bind the object, that it doesn't need to be explicitly returned via the response body.